# How to call another method when we are using RabbitMQ Publish and Subscriber pattern?

Tags: rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

I have a program where i need to process transactions from two sources, first one is from RabbitMQ and another from Database. For first one, I am using RabbitMQ publish and subscriber pattern so that whenever if any transactions comes into queue then this method can process that transaction, but the problem with publish and subscriber pattern is, it's not giving control to other methods. If transactions are processed from queue then it is waiting for new transactions. I know this is the behavior of this pattern, but how to call other method(transactions from database) in between if there is no transactions in queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem using the below code

```
private void Poll()
    {
        while (Enabled)
        {
            try
            {
                BasicDeliverEventArgs objBasicDeliverEventArgs;
                //Get next message
                var boolMessageRecieved = _subscription.Next(60000, out objBasicDeliverEventArgs);
                //Deserialize message
                if (boolMessageRecieved)
                {
                    var objEvent = DeSerialize(objBasicDeliverEventArgs.Body);
                    if (objEvent != null)
                    {
                        registerService.Process(objEvent);
                        _subscription.Ack();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //DB realted process.
                    Console.WriteLine("Idle time because there is no messages in queue");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //log
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fun stuff. Truth about CPython is it is essentially single threaded thanks to the GIL. So when a subscriber thread is running - I am guessing you are using threads - the subscriber is actually polling for new messages and thus always busy and so it never relinquishes control to the db thread. Solutions: switching to multiprocessing module instead of threading. Or you can interleave polling RabbitMQ and working ur database thread.